# Enforce composite unique constraint that depends on parent column value

Tags: mysql, sql, constraints, database-normalization, unique-constraint

With provided schema i want to somehow enforce that there is unique reserved_seat:seat_id per showing. In other words you can't reserve specific seat if it is already reserved in that showing.

One option is to also add showing_id to reservation_seat (which is redundant) and then make unique constraint on (showing_id, seat_id).

Can this be done in sql or it falls to application code?

[image]

The DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE showing
(
    id              INT  NOT NULL  AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name            VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

CREATE TABLE reservation
(
    id              INT  NOT NULL  AUTO_INCREMENT,
    showing_id      INT  NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (showing_id) REFERENCES showing(id)
)

CREATE TABLE reservation_seat
(
    id              INT  NOT NULL  AUTO_INCREMENT,
    reservation_id  INT  NOT NULL,
    seat_id         INT  NOT NULL,
    confirmed       TINYINT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (reservation_id) REFERENCES reservation(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (seat_id) REFERENCES seat(id)
)

CREATE TABLE seat
(
    id              INT  NOT NULL  AUTO_INCREMENT,
    row             VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    column          VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Comment: People want to see table definitions as *text*, not images.  And especially not images with faint grey lines on a black background.

Comment: @GordonLinoff If it would help you to answer my question I'll gladly change it.

Comment: What is a "reservation"?  4 adjacent seats for that one night?

Comment: This is a very interesting question.  I would suggest moving or reposting it at https://dba.stackexchange.com where you are likely to get more answers and attention. I would also recommend following @GordonLinoff's advice and post the table definitions as SQL command text rather than a diagram image.  (if you do repost, be sure to close/delete this one).

Comment: I'll go ahead and make the SQL command text for you ...

Comment: Ok, I've added the DDL text.  The "row" and "column" names may need quoting, I'll leave that to you

Comment: Hmm, now I feel invested in it so I think that I will try to answer it here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that this is one of those rare cases where the use of surrogate keys (auto_increment id's) instead of natural keys has led you astray.  Consider how your table definitions would look if you used natural keys instead:

```
CREATE TABLE showing
(
    name            VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,   -- globally unique
    PRIMARY KEY (name)
)

CREATE TABLE reservation
(
    showing_name    VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    name            VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,   -- only unique within showing_name
    PRIMARY KEY (name, showing_name),
    FOREIGN KEY (showing_name) REFERENCES showing(name)
)

CREATE TABLE reservation_seat
(
    showing_name    VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    reservation_name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    seat_row        VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    seat_column     VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    confirmed       TINYINT,
    PRIMARY KEY (showing_name, reservation_name, seat_row, seat_column),
    FOREIGN KEY (showing_name, reservation_name) REFERENCES reservation(showing_name, name),
    FOREIGN KEY (seat_row, seat_column) REFERENCES seat(row, column)
)
```

Now you can add your reserved seat per showing constraint as an Alternate Key on reservation_seat:

```
CREATE TABLE reservation_seat
(
    showing_name    VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    reservation_name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    seat_row        VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    seat_column     VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    confirmed       TINYINT,
    PRIMARY KEY (showing_name, reservation_name, seat_row, seat_column),
    FOREIGN KEY (showing_name, reservation_name) REFERENCES reservation(showing_name, name),
    FOREIGN KEY (seat_row, seat_column) REFERENCES seat(row, column),
    CONSTRAINT UC_seat_showing_reserved UNIQUE(showing_name, seat_row, seat_column)
)
```

However, this makes it clear that the primary key is superfluous because it's just a weaker version of the constraint that we have added, so we should replace it with our new constraint.

```
CREATE TABLE reservation_seat
(
    showing_name    VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    reservation_name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    seat_row        VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    seat_column     VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    confirmed       TINYINT,
    PRIMARY KEY (showing_name, seat_row, seat_column),
    FOREIGN KEY (showing_name, reservation_name) REFERENCES reservation(showing_name, name),
    FOREIGN KEY (seat_row, seat_column) REFERENCES seat(row, column)
)
```

We may worry now that our reservation_seat could be referencing a reservation with a different showing_id than the reservation_seat itself,  but that's not a problem for natural keys because the first foreign key reference prevents that.

Now all we need to do is to translate this back into surrogate keys:

```
CREATE TABLE reservation_seat
(
    id              INT  NOT NULL  AUTO_INCREMENT,
    showing_id      INT  NOT NULL,
    reservation_id  INT  NOT NULL,
    seat_id         INT  NOT NULL,
    confirmed       TINYINT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (showing_id, reservation_id) REFERENCES reservation(showing_id, id),
    FOREIGN KEY (seat_id) REFERENCES seat(id),
    CONSTRAINT UC_seat_showing_reserved UNIQUE(showing_id, seat_id)
)
```

Because we're making the reservation_seat(id) the primary key, we have to change the named PK definition back into a unique constraint.  Compared to your original reservation_seat definition, we end up with showing_id added, but with the modified stronger first foreign key definition we now insure both that reservation_seat are unique within a showing and  that reservation_seat cannot have a showing_id different from its parent reservation.

(Note: you will probably have to quote the 'row' and 'column' column names in the SQL code above)

**Additional Note:** DBMS's vary on this (and I am not sure about MySql in this case), but many will require that a Foreign Key relation have a corresponding Primary Key or Unique Constraint on the target (referenced) table.  This would mean that you would have to alter the *reservation* table with a new constraint like:

```
CONSTRAINT UC_showing_reserved UNIQUE(showing_id, id)
```

to match the new FK definition on *reservation_seat* that I suggested above:

```
FOREIGN KEY (showing_id, reservation_id) REFERENCES reservation(showing_id, id),
```

Technically, this would be a redundant constraint since it is a weaker version of the primary key on the reservation table, but in this case SQL would probably still require it to implement the FK.

Comment: (FYI this is why we like DB definitions in text instead of images)

Answer (score 0):

Does it take 90 characters to specify a "seat"?  The seats I am familiar with are like "103-45" or "J17".  Or even "Sec 4 Row 43 Seat 105".  You have not mentioned it, but row/column is not adequate to answer the question "are these two seats adjacent?"

My first approach to the problem is to get rid of the table `seat`, other than being able to enumerate all the seats in a venue.

Then I would question the table `reservation_seat`, which smells like a many-to-many mapping (plus a flag).  Many:many implies non uniqueness.  So, something has to give.

The raw, unnormalized, data seems to be

```
showing:  showing_id (PK), date, time, location
reservation:  showing_id, seat, confirmed
```

Having this (on `reservation`) probably answers your question:

```
PRIMARY KEY(showing_id, seat)
```

It ties the two tables together, provides a 'natural' PK, and still allows for the `confirmed` flag.

I don't know your logic for "confirming".  I assume that you cannot reassign a seat while it is waiting to be confirmed?

Back to my starting comment.  `seat VARCHAR(15)` might be appropriate.  And, if you need it, another table could have

```
CREATE TABLE venue (
    venue_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR (144) NOT NULL,
    location ...
    capacity SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY(venue_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB

CREATE TABLE seat (
    venue_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    seat_num VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    is_handicap ...,
    strip_num SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,  -- see below
    PRIMARY KEY(venue_id, seat_num)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

This fails to take care of a venue where you sometimes want to block off the balcony, thereby invalidating some of the seats.  Having a different `venue` and `id` with most of the info the same might be direction to take.

Be sure to use transactions (`BEGIN..COMMIT` and `FOR UPDATE`) where appropriate.

```
CREATE TABLE showing (
    showing_id MEDIUM UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    venue_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    date ...
    notes ...
    PRIMARY KEY(showing_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

To deal with seat adjacency, I suggest *manually* assign each stretch of *adjacent* seats a "strip" number that stops at aisles, posts, etc.  Alas, that is not adequate for a middle section where seat "1" is in the middle, with even numbers going one way and odd going the other way.  So K-8 and K-9 are quite far apart, but K-8 and K-10 are adjacent, in spite sorting far apart.

As for `confirmed`, it "belongs" in `reservation`.  But it might be more convenient for other actions to have it in `seat`.  We may need to work out the SQL statements to make that decision.  Also, the SQL statements are necessary for deciding on what secondary `INDEXes` to have.